# Conditional Commit maven-scm-plugin

Tags: git, maven, maven-release-plugin, maven-scm

Is there a way not to commit test.html to scm if there is no changes?

Since, when you commit an unchanged file with *git commit*, it gives ***nothing to commit***

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-scm-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <connectionType>connection</connectionType>
    </configuration>
    <inherited>false</inherited>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>add-version-to-git</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>checkin</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <basedir>${project.basedir}</basedir>
                <includes>test.html</includes>
                <message>Test HTML Update</message>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: If there is not change you can't do a commit neither with SVN nor with Git...apart from it that it does not make sense.

Comment: Yes, but it is the part of release management. So, I wonder is there a workaround for maven-scm-plugin to check the included items first and then exclude them if they are not changed?

Comment: Hm...Are those files changed or not? If i correctly understand they are not changed so they can't be checked in neither with Git or SVN...I don't understand the need for them? in particular in the basedir ? What not packaging those html file into a zip file during the release process and deploy it with the rest of your artifacts?

Answer (score 0):

Maven profile activation may be used, like:

```
<activation>
    <property>
        <name>testChanged</name>
    </property>
</activation>
```

The **testChanged** property can be set where the changing is being made.